# Extracting sub objects from list in

Tags: r

I have the following list in R

```
> str(Grades.Good)
List of 2
 $ FALSE: Named num [1:10] 89 74 64 61 55 80 78 73 57 87
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "Bettie" "Dona" "Frances" "Gerri"       ...
 $ TRUE : Named num [1:5] 94 97 94 91 92
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "Alana" "Consuela" "Elaine" "Kenyatta" ...
```

I am trying to extract the names from the second item, Grades.Good[2].  I have tried:

```
> names(Grades.Good[2])
[1] "TRUE"
> names(Grades.Good)[2]
[1] "TRUE"
> names(Grades.Good$TRUE)
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "names(Grades.Good$TRUE"
```

What is the best way to extract a character vector with just the names "Alana" "Consuela" "Elaine" "Kenyatta" ...?

Comment: How did you get data into that format (you're going to have a heck of a time with data structures like that). For your case, do `names(Grades.Good$\`TRUE\`)`

Comment: @hrbrmstr - Possibly the result from `split` on a logical vector.  Phil, it seems you might just need to use `Grades.Good[[2]]` instead of `Grades.Good[2]`

Comment: That data structure was the result of a split() function.

Comment: Wow, base R can really crank out some horribad data structures at times :-)

Comment: Thanks, I need to research nested object referencing with multiple square brackets.